# Finding object in nested collection with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have a collection of teams (in a league) like so:

```
var fra1 = {
   "sports":[
      {
         "name":"soccer",
         "id":600,
         "uid":"s:600",
         "leagues":[
            {
               "name":"French Ligue 1",
               "abbreviation":"fra.1",
               "id":710,
               "isTournament":false,
               "country":{
                  "id":7,
                  "name":"France",
                  "abbreviation":"FRA"
               },
               "uid":"s:600~l:710",
               "groupId":9,
               "shortName":"Ligue 1",
               "teams":[
                  {
                     "id":159,
                     "uid":"s:600~t:159",
                     "location":"Bordeaux",
                     "name":"Bordeaux",
                     "nickname":"Bordeaux",
                     "abbreviation":"BOR",
                     "color":"00003e",
                  },
                  {
                     "id":160,
                     "uid":"s:600~t:160",
                     "location":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
                     "name":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
                     "nickname":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
                     "abbreviation":"PSG",
                     "color":"000040",
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
}
```

There are about 20 teams in each var stored in this way. Then, I have about six such leagues: `eng1`, `esp1`, `fra1`, `ger1`, `ita1`, and `usa1`. I put those in another collection, like so:

```
var all = {
    "eng1":eng1,
    "esp1":esp1,
    "fra1":fra1,
    "ger1":ger1,
    "ita1":ita1,
    "usa1":usa1
}
```

Now, each team (regardless of the league they're in) has a unique ID: in the above example, Bordeaux has ID 159, PSG has ID 160, and so on. So I want to be able to search the `all` collection for a unique team by `teamid`, using Underscore.js, but I can't quite get the syntax down. I know I could search one league like so:

```
var obj = _.find(fra1.sports[0].leagues[0].teams, function(obj) { return obj.id == teamid })
```

But I can't figure out how to do it across all six leagues. Can anyone help? I'd prefer not to have to combine the collections into one manually, that would be cumbersome with the amount of data involved.

EDIT: I'm currently using:

```
for (var league in all)
{
    var obj = _.find(all[league].sports[0].leagues[0].teams, function(obj) { return obj.id == teamid })

    if (obj !== undefined)
    {   
        // do things
    }
}
```

But would still like something nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a map of the teams with the team id as the key and the team as the value:

```
var teams = {};

_.each(all, function(nation){
    _.each(nation.sports[0].leagues[0].teams, function(team){
        teams[team.id] = team;
    });
});
```

You could then access the team using the key:

```
var psg = teams[160];
```

Comment: This assumes you only have one sport per nation and one league per sport.

Comment: Which is what the OP is currently using.

Comment: Good point, I still prefer _.groupBy to looping through with _.each and manually building the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As far as parsing the rest of the teams, just use chain:

```
var allTeams = _.chain(all)
  .values()
  .pluck('sports').flatten()  // once
  .pluck('leagues').flatten() // twice
  .pluck('teams').flatten()   // third time's a charm
  .value()
```

I would recommend using _.groupBy() on teamID. This will give you a hash-table (JS object) that maps `teamID -> teamObject`. Say you have your teams parsed like this:

```
var allTeams =[
{
  "id":159,
  "uid":"s:600~t:159",
  "location":"Bordeaux",
  "name":"Bordeaux",
  "nickname":"Bordeaux",
  "abbreviation":"BOR",
  "color":"00003e",
},{
  "id":160,
  "uid":"s:600~t:160",
  "location":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
  "name":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
  "nickname":"Paris Saint-Germain ",
  "abbreviation":"PSG",
  "color":"000040",
}]
```

You can group them with:

```
var lookup = _.groupBy(teams, 'id')
```

And then look up a team like this:

```
var myTeam = lookup[teamId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do additional loops over the `sports` and `leagues`, not only over `all`:

```
for (var league in all) {
    var sports = all[league];
    for (var i=0; i<sports.length; i++) {
        var leagues = sports[i].leagues;
        for (var j=0; j<leagues.length; j++) {
            var teams = leagues[j].teams;
            // var obj = _.find(teams, function(obj) { return obj.id == teamid })
            for (var k=0; k<teams.length; k++) {
                var obj = teams[k];
                if (obj.id == teamid) {
                    … // do things
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```